# Dynamic height for custom collection view cell by using autolayouts

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I had created a custom collection view cell. It has a **UILabel**, **UIView**, **UIButton** and then **UITextView**.

*Requirements are*:

1. UILabel's text size can be anything. Based on that it's content size label must **re-size**. It is working properly.
2. any number of views can be added to UIView. Based on that this UIView must be **re-size**.
3. UIButton is just a normal button. when we click on it, the below TextView will toggle.

The constraints that I applied are:

[image]

Comment: collection view will cell size is based on its content?

Answer (score -1):

use this method and calculate the size that is appropriate for you and return it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let Labell : UILabel = UILabel()

    Labell.text =   self.items[indexPath.item]
    let labelTextHeight =   Labell.intrinsicContentSize.height
    //calculate size for UIView, UIButton, TextView and then add it
    return CGSize(width: /*fix width*/, height: labelTextHeigh + /*your UIView height and other height*/)

}
```

don't forget to extend your `viewController` from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Comment: please tell me how to calculate the size's @Rock Balbao

Comment: @Rock Balbao, where you have assigned text of uilabel.

Comment: I am creating a temporary label which takes the text as label.text and calculates its height thus in this way I will get the size of the label that will be used at real time. and I can set the height of collection view and as label's height + some space you want to keep in between the cells. @RahulPatel

Comment: @RamcharanReddy Tell me what can be there in your UIView? and textview. use intrinsic height of those 3(button,view,textview) add with label's height and then return it

Comment: the UIView can be added with any number of subviews like custom radio buttons, checkboxes and etc. button has fixed height. TextView also has fixed height but it will toggle. @RockBalbao

Comment: before going in to cellForItemAt() method , sizeForItemAt() will get execute
which means before assigning any data, we can not give the size

Comment: Where are you getting your data from? let me give you full working code

Comment: data from Webservices. As soon as I get the complete data from web services, then collection view will start loading. Yea. Please provide the full working code. @RockBalbao

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135245/discussion-between-ramcharan-reddy-and-rock-balbao).